# Angular Reactive Forms Generate Form Controls from Type

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

So, I have my Client class in TypeScript, let's say I have:

```
export class Client {
   id: string = '';
   name: string = '';
   email: string = '';
}
```

Now every time I want to create a new Client I need a form, that's how I build it:

```
this.currentClient = new FormGroup({
  id: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
  name: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
  email: new FormControl(false)
}
```

Then I add the form to the html:

```
    <form [formGroup]="currentClient" (submit)="submit($event)">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" formControlName="id" class="form-control" placeholder="Id">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" formControlName="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" formControlName="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
        </div>

        <button  [disabled]="currentContragent.invalid" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>

    </form>
```

That's fine but I have some really big classes with more than 30 fields inside. For each, I have to create a TS class, a form group and I have to add it to the html. Is there anything like:

```
this.currentClient = formGroupFromType(typeof(Client));
```

And then something that could automatically generate my html using ng-for or something?

I was thinking of building my own class that could hold property name, type, default value, isRequired and some other information like what editor (textbox, numeric textbox, etc). Having a list of properties defined like this could be used to generate the form group and the html, but it won't be strongly typed as I don't see how it could be connected to the Client class.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: I don't think I can write code but you'd approach this using FormArray and nest new Client-based FormGroups within them. You could use JSON to output the form controls if you feel the need to "model" each form type. Am I on the right path?

Comment: ask to google for "angular dynamic forms" is a good sugestion?

Answer (score 1):

I kind of wrote pseudo code here and I hope it helps.

**Component**

```
//public form: FormGroup;
//private fb: FormBuilder

form = <FormGroup>this.fb.group({
    forms: this.fb.array(null),
});

addFormByType(formType){
    newForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup();
    // build up the form 
    // possibly by looping through the formType JSON model
    // or call a method to offload form creation by formType 
    (<FormArray>this.form.get('forms')).push(newForm);
}
```

**Template (view)**
From [Angular docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArrayName#example)

```
  <div formArrayName="forms">
    <div *ngFor="let city of form.controls['forms'].controls; index as i">
      <input formControlName="{{i}}">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Higher level: I would create a ControlValueAccessor (CVA) component for each form type. Then your code will be easier to work with and maintain.

Comment: That's cool but I don't understand how could I could build the form.

Comment: Your form has to be dynamic as the user adds new group types right? Each group type should be a FormGroup added to the main FormArray.

Comment: It doesn't need to be dynamic, I just want it to hold the same fields as the class without me having to define them (my 2nd code block in the question).